# Formulating a matrix linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

I want to find the $X$ that solves the matrix equation

$$ AX = B $$

with $A$ and $B$ known, moreover:

- $ A$ and $X$ are rectangular, $A$ is $n \times m $ and $X$ is an $m \times n$, with $m > n$.
- $B$ is diagonal with non-zero entries (and is therefore invertible).
- The rows of $X$ must sum to $ \leq 1. $
- The entries of $X$ lie between 0 and 1.
- if $A_{ij} = 0 $ then we know that $X_{ji} = 0$.
- $A$ is pretty sparse (in fact, usually each row will have an average of ~3 non zero entries)
- I expect that the system has many solutions, so that $ \det(A^TA) = 0 $

I was trying to solve this using different numerical iterative methods [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method#Convergence_of_Krylov_subspace_methods) but I am told given the number of inequalities, linear programming is actually the way forward.

Though I am not sure the framework for setting all this up. If we take $0$ as the objective function, how would one encode the very many constraints?

Any hints in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

For more context:

- $A_{ji}$ represents the maximum number of spaces that an entity $j$ can take up, in within region $i$
- $X_{ij}$ is the ratio of entity $j$ in region $i$
- The diagonal entries of $B$ therefore present the total actual spaces taken up by entity $j$, across all regions $i$.
- For dimensions, specifically for my case, $ m = 250$ and $n = 15$. This puts $4000$ unknowns in $X$, although very many are zero.
- The regions indexed by $I$, are in this case chosen based of the different intersections of entities in a region. All entities have an influence on one another - we are making the naive assumption that within any region $i$, the ratio of entity $j$ in this region $i$ is constant.
- So in reality this means $A$ is very sparse (usually, no more two or three entities are competing in a group) and also, it means that the ratio $X_{ij}$ can be assumed to be zero when $A_{ji}$ is zero.

Comment: Hint: Just use 0 as the objective function and add all the required constraints. Then your minimization problem is basically a feasibility problem.

Comment: There seem to be some typos in the question (such as the second bullet item ending with "Here $X$"). It might help to review and edit it.

Comment: thank you - I didn't even notice them after putting it here in a rush! it is fixed now.

Comment: @joni I tried this using lpsolve in R but I'm struggling to find out how to input this framework in a way that isn't giving me zeros everywhere.

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull Are you saying that the solution you get from lpsolve sets $X_{i,j}=0$ for all $i,j?$ If so, and assuming $B$ is not identically zero, your model must contain errors.

Comment: Thank you, there are for sure errors in how I'm setting it up. it remains unclear how I can solve this - $ X $ is not a vector, it is a matrix, with constraints across its rows and columns as well as individual elements. Do I need to use MOLP on the columns of $X$?